# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE on WINDOWS not WORKING

Tags: mysql, file-io, load, local

I am using a windows with MySQL 8.0 installed.

I have checked the solutions already posted on stackoverflow but these had no immediate results.

I have set the global variable with `SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;`
This options seems to be enable now but MySQL keeps throwing the following error:

Error Code:

> 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Can anyone help me out to remedy this behavior ?

Comment: See [6.1.6 Security Issues with LOAD DATA LOCAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html).

Comment: I have tried SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1 and it says it is on but it is not working. I think this command is for the server side ? How do I set the option --local-infile=1 as suggested by the MySQL documentation? I have no experience with the MySQL console. Could you provide me the full syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

File: `Z:\Path\To\MySQL\Files\my_file.csv`:

```bsh
1,"a string"
2,"a string containing a , comma"
3,"a string containing a \" quote"
4,"a string containing a \", quote and comma"
```

MySQL Command-Line:

```sql
Z:\>mysql
Enter password: **************
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 8.0.11 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `_`.`my_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_`.`my_table` (
    ->   `col0` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `col1` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.45 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE `variable_name` = 'secure_file_priv';
+------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                   |
+------------------+-------------------------+
| secure_file_priv | Z:\Path\To\MySQL\Files\ |
+------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Z:\\Path\\To\\MySQL\\Files\\my_file.csv'
    ->   INTO TABLE `_`.`my_table`
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.`local_infile`;
+-------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.`local_infile` |
+-------------------------+
|                       0 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @@GLOBAL.`local_infile` := 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.`local_infile`;
+-------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.`local_infile` |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Z:\\Path\\To\\MySQL\\Files\\my_file.csv'
    ->   INTO TABLE `_`.`my_table`
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

mysql> SELECT `col0`, `col1`
    -> FROM `_`.`my_table`;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye

Z:\>mysql --local-infile=1
Enter password: **************
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 8.0.11 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.`local_infile`;
+-------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.`local_infile` |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Z:\\Path\\To\\MySQL\\Files\\my_file.csv'
    ->   INTO TABLE `_`.`my_table`
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.19 sec)
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `col0`, `col1`
    -> FROM `_`.`my_table`;
+------+------------------------------------------+
| col0 | col1                                     |
+------+------------------------------------------+
|    1 | a string                                 |
|    2 | a string containing a , comma            |
|    3 | a string containing a " quote            |
|    4 | a string containing a ", quote and comma |
+------+------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is there also a way to set the --local-infile=1 option when you run this from the mySQL command line (thus not from the windows command prompt) ? How should you enter that ?

Comment: @NikolaasReyns: `mysql supports the following options, which can be specified on the command line or in the [mysql] and [client] groups of an option file.`, see [4.5.1.1 mysql Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html).

Comment: I have checked this and added the --local-infile=1 option. When I connect with MySQL command line Client, I can see that the option is enable but it does not work. However, when I try it with my command prompt from windows, it works... I need to find a way to run these command in a shell because it has to be integrated in an automated ETL-process.

Comment: @NikolaasReyns: How will you connect your ETL-process to the database?.

Comment: I don't understand why this finally fixed it compared to all other ways I set that variable but it did. Unfortunately it only worked for the CLI but better than nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem after a search, I solve the problem by removing the local keyword from the query.

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

The query should return: ON

The query should look like this:

```
load data infile 'C:\\CA_DRU_proj_2010-2060.csv'
into table pop_proj
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines;
```

**You should be noticed that I removed the local keyword from here and now it works fine.**

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2019, this is an unresolved bug with MySQL Workbench 8.0.12. See: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91891 .

Executing the same command through the CLI should work, however, provided the "local_infile" global variable has been set to 1:

> SET @@GLOBAL.local_infile=1;

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with a similar problem, using MySQL 8.0.19 on Windows.
I was able to resolve by NOT using the LOCAL keyword AND 
using the Windows Services manager (type Services on the explorer taskbar), right clicking on MySQL80 ->selecting Properties, then on the Log On tab, changing the Log On As: value to Local System Account.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 users: it is worth repeating how important it is to confirm which account Windows is using to run the MySQL service.

This problem continued in MySQL 8.0.21 in Windows 10.  With `LOAD DATA INFILE` (and **not** `LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL`, which requires an additional file transfer even if you're running client and server on the same desktop) I started receiving this error:

`not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)`

For some reason, MySQL decided to select "Network Services", possibly because I moved the installation from the default C: drive to a faster physical drive on D:

**NO:**
[image: No. Wrong. Gives not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied error]

The original installation had set up Local I selected the radio button for "Local System Account" and that solved it for me.

**YES:**
[image: Original and correct configuration]

The [mySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-start-service.html) encourages running mySQL on Windows as a Windows Service, but it gives no recommendation as to which account to specify as the log on for the service.

As many others have, I went through all the options (local_infile etc.) but did not check the service logon until I saw [the answer from CesarinG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60406945/5839677), to whom I now owe a beer or coffee.